# git branching and commit confusion

Tags: git

I am unable to merge my commit to my master branch in github.

This is step by step of whatever I have done/tried

```
git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git add . 
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git commit -m "Final Production working build"
[detached HEAD 46a7f55] Final Production working build
 28 files changed, 87 insertions(+), 29 deletions(-)
g rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png (97%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png (98%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/icon.png (99%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png (99%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png (99%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/icon.png (98%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png (99%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png (98%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/icon.png (98%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (98%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png (98%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/icon.png (98%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (97%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png (99%)
 rewrite android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/icon.png (98%)
 delete mode 100644 src/images/123.png
 delete mode 100644 src/images/angel.jpg
 delete mode 100644 src/images/facebook.png
 delete mode 100644 src/images/instagram.png
 delete mode 100644 src/images/twitter.jpg
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git push 
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>

Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ 
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git checkout master
Warning: you are leaving 2 commits behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  46a7f55 Final Production working build
  3af30c2 Victory Native graphs work

If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> 46a7f55

Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git push
Everything up-to-date
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git checkout splashscreen
Branch 'splashscreen' set up to track remote branch 'splashscreen' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'splashscreen'
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git push
Everything up-to-date
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git status .
On branch splashscreen
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/splashscreen'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git add .
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$ git commit -m "production build"
On branch splashscreen
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/splashscreen'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Anils-MacBook-Pro:React-native-crypto anilbhatia$
```

Now, I am unable to see my last work, which I think is because I did "git checkout master" and "git checkout splashscreen".

I can fix that by going back to this commit  `46a7f55 Final Production working build` but then how can I push to my github?

Comment: Please see [Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) that commit  46a7f55 (done outside of any branch, in a detached HEAD mode) to the right branch:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick  46a7f55 
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     To verify the current branch and status. Just do 
>     git status
>
>    Looks like you are not in branch
> ```

"You are not currently on a branch".

```
    git checkout splashscreen

     if you want to merge master changes to splash screen just do
     git merge master.
```

if you want splash screen changes to master, checkout to master 
       git checkout master
       git merge splashscreen.

```
  or else if you know the commit id, you could do
  git cherry-pick <commid-ID>
  git push
```